# SNS mails though cloudwatch metric filter

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch

**Hi All,**

**Requirement**: I need a SNS alert mail whenever specific keywords flow into CloudWatch logs.

**Solution**: I created a metric filter in CloudWatch logs and set an Alarm to the filter which will be triggered when the specific keyword matches, the alarm will trigger a SNS topic for mail alert to me.

**Challenge**: SNS mail is too vague and doesn't carry the actual logs in mail.

Any help is apapreciated :)

Thanks in advance!!